# How to extrude while obtaining better topology?

Tags: modeling, scripting

I have an issue regarding the extrude operation.

If you avec a plane split in 4 face and you want to extrude each one of them in separate manner, blender will create 2 faces at the border each time. See shape 1 and 2.

[image: I'm looking to get from shape 1 to 3]

Meanwhile I'm looking to get something similar to shape 3 where the topology is cleaner (now double face and less edges ).

Is there anyway to get this result in blender ?

Any help is welcome.

Here is the figure with face orientation in cas the other one isn't clear enough :
[image: With face orientation]

Comment: Yes you can accomplish that by selecting edges.

Comment: Yes that what I did to get shape 3, deleted the edges and added the missing faces, but I want to do that to an extended scale where manual work is not an option. I was wondering if there is a similar operator or maybe a way to script that.

Comment: Automating will be more difficult. Pretty much anything is possible via add-ons though, if you're willing to go down that road.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the following steps to get a clean topology with the same shape.

Select the first face and extrude downwards.
[image]

[image]

Now switch to edge select and select the other faces and the outer perimeter.
[image]

[image]

Repeat the same technique shown in the last two steps.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the topology will be clean but you added way more vertices, edges and faces than necessary. I'm looking for something that would give efficient result in topology and poly count.

Comment: What polygons do you think are unnecessary? If you want to keep it all quads you can't really remove anything.

Comment: Al thought adding a decimate modifier with the planar option will delete them, but the modifier can be at bit slow when the shape is too complex...

Comment: I was willing to go full n-gons to be honest.

Comment: @EdmondBoulet-Gilly that isn't really considered good/clean topology. Not sure why you'd want that, but you could manually make them n-gons, I suppose. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯